# unknown client trying to connect watson IoT device continiously

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson

i had connected Watson IoT-sensor-Simulator to Watson IoT device by entering device credentials, a few days back and closed the connection.

now the device is continuously connected and receiving messages as"The client id was reused" thereby increasing the data usage rate .

I need help in disconnecting the connection.
[message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcnxx.png)

Answer (score 2):

The log messages showing "The client ID was reused" indicates that you are running multiple clients using the same credentials - so although you have closed the connection from one client, the other clients continue to connect. If you can't find these clients (the log messages will contain the IP addresses to help you find them) then you can revoke access for the other clients by changing the device's password. This will prevent the spurious clients from connecting.